# How does linux decide the interface to route an application's traffic from?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, routing, network-interface

I have a virtualised Linux box running with two interfaces, say `int1` and `int2`. `int1` is a "NAT-Network" and `int2` is a "Host-Only" adapter on VirtualBox.

I do not receive any response if I try to ping "google.com" from the terminal as the traffic is being routed from `int2`. But, if I try to visit "google.com" in the browser, it responds without a problem.

Since both, terminal and Firefox, are simply applications I wonder how does the Linux decide which application's traffic should be routed through which interface and how may I change it.

PS: The Linux box is actually "Linux Backbox", an Ubuntu based OS, in case it matters.

PPS: I know I can go for bridged connection if I want to access both, the internet and the host OS from my guest OS but this is my company's computer I'm working on and I don't want the IT department to go around searching for a ghost machine on the network with a "spooky" hostname (It's literally "spooky" :D ).

Comment: Can you post the (formatted) output of `/sbin/route -n` on the VM machine?

Comment: @ivanivan : I'm home now. I'll post tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux decides which interface to use through rules and routes.

The rules specify conditions of the packet and which routing table should be consulted, the rules can be seen with `ip rule show` if you are using iproute2. Mostly, this just states to look at the local, main and then default tables in that order.

The routing tables simply contain lists of destinations and who the packet should be next sent to (including the interface which it should be sent off). The *main* routing table can be checked with `ip route show`.

AFAIK Linux doesn't use different routes for different applications (providing they are in the same network namespace and you haven't got some weird iptables fwmarking system).